# PostgreSQL DROP DATABASE privilege?

Tags: postgresql

I am in an environment where I'd like to grant some users the `CREATEDB` privilege. But I can't find a privilege option for allowing/disallowing people to DROP their databases.

Is there a way to grant users privileges to create databases, but forbid them to drop databases? (So that they won't accidentally delete each others' databases)

Comment: A user can only drop database that he owns. The `createdb` privilege will not break that